# My page keep redirect back to login page when I try to login (LARAVEL)

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, middleware, guzzle

I tried to make login page . By using `middleware` , i should able to redirect to main page when I click sign in button but when i hit sign in button , its return redirect back to my login page. Here is my code

Authenticate.php (middleware)

```
protected function redirectTo($request)
    {
        if (! $request->expectsJson()) {
            return route('login');
        }
    }
```

web.php  (route)

```
Route::get('/', 'AuthController@index')->name('login');


Route::post('/login', 'AuthController@login')->middleware('auth')->name('welcome');
```

AuthController.php

```
public function index(Request $request) {


        return view('auth.login');


    }



    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $username = $request->username;
        $pass = $request->password;

        $password = base64_encode(sha1($pass, true));


          $options = [
            'headers' => [
                'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
                'Accept' => 'application/json',

            ],

            'query' => [

                'username' => $username,
                'password' => $password,
            ]
        ];



        $response = $this->client->post('userLogin', $options)->getBody();
        $content = json_decode($response->getContents());





        if($content == null)
        {

            return redirect()->back()->with('error', 'Username not exist');
        }
            return view('welcome.dashboard');  //expected redirect to dashboard after login



    }
```

the login data was from backend api . I just pull data by using guzzle .Sorry if my explaination not clear but i hope its help and sorry for my bad english

Comment: is the return view inside foreach loop ? and why are you looping and checking multiple times the password ?

Comment: just want to access the array even i just got one array return

Comment: So the the view which you are returning, is it inside this foreach loop ? or outside ?

Comment: outside the loop . sorry i just deleted some code to make it short and maybe i just accidentally delete curly bracket which make u confused

Comment: As far as i know, you are checking the user for logging in, inside a foreach loop, so this process will be repeating itself, means will be redirecting you again and again.

Comment: no sir if you check my route i think my middleware got problem . because when i remove middleware from my route the login works but the objective not achieved which non user can access my dashboard page

Comment: Then you don't need auth middleware on your login route, that is causing the problem, and also let me know do you have multiple users like admin or other users which you don't wanna login them ?

Comment: i just got only one user and i want to prevent user guest that has not log in access my dashboard . From what i know , to prevent that u need to use middleware ? any  solution?

Comment: You just got only 1 user, but is the guest user also store in your users table ? and is there any flag for the users ? like type 1 for admin and type 0 for guest users ? then you can use middleware